# How to filter noise in nested tags in JSoup? java

Tags: java, html, xml, parsing, jsoup

How to filter noise in nested tags? For example, i have this input:

**[in:]**

```
<html>
  <source>
     <noise>something something, many many things</noise>foo bar bar<noise>more something something noise</noise>baring foo
  </source>
</html>
```

and i need to get this output:

**[out]**

```
foo bar bar
baring foo
```

I have tried this but I am still getting the noise from the nested tags:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.parser.Parser;

public class HelloJsoup {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String br = "<html><source><noise>something something, many many things</noise>foo bar bar<noise>more something something noise</noise>baring foo</source></html>";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(br, "", Parser.xmlParser());
        //System.out.println(doc);
        for (Element sentence : doc.getElementsByTag("source"))
            System.out.print(sentence.text());

    }
}
```

**[out:]**

```
something something, many many thingsfoo bar barmore something something noisebaring foo
```

Comment: FYI I updated my answer because I found a simpler method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By removing the noise tags first, you are left with `<source>foo bar barbaring foo</source>`, though to achieve the output you specified, you can just iterate through the nodes and print each TextNode on a new line. For example:

```
String br = "<html><source><noise>something something, many many things</noise>foo bar bar<noise>more something something noise</noise>baring foo</source></html>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(br, "", Parser.xmlParser());

Element source = doc.select("source").first(); // select source element

Elements noise = doc.select("noise");          // Select noise elements
for (Element e : noise) {                      // loop through and remove each from doc
    e.remove();
}

for (Node node : source.childNodes()) {
    System.out.println(node);                  // print each remaining textnode on a new line
}
```

Outputs:

```
foo bar bar
baring foo
```

---

**Update**

I found this to be an even simpler method:

```
Element source = doc.select("source").first(); // select source element

for (TextNode node : source.textNodes()) {
    System.out.println(node);
}
```

It iterates through the textNodes owned directly by the `<source>` element and prints each one to a new line. Ouput is:

```
foo bar bar
baring foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
System.out.println(sentence.ownText());
```

Comment: `sentence.ownText()` returns the right set of strings but there's some spacing issues. Any way to resolve this?